# backdrop: 'static' is not working for ngDialog modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui

I want to prevent the modal from closing when clicked outside or pressing `esc` in keyboard. So I used `backdrop:'static'` and `keyboard:false` like below,

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngDialog', 'chatSocket']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.openChatBox = function() {
      ngDialog.openConfirm({
        template: 'chatBox.html',
        controller: 'msgController',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        scope: $scope //Pass the scope object if you need to access in the template
    }).then(
        function(value) {
            //You need to implement the saveForm() method which should return a promise object
            $scope.closeChat().then(

            );
        },
        function(value) {
            //Cancel or do nothing
        }
    );
};

});
```

The button clicked to open the modal is,

```
 <button ng-click="openChatBox()" >Open</button>
```

What is the problem with my code, why is not working?

Comment: What is this `ngDialog.openConfirm`?? Nomally we use `$modal.open`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `$modal`, we use `backdrop` and `keyboard` options to achieve it, but for `ngDialog` the options are `closeByDocument` and `closeByEscape`.

```
$scope.openChatBox = function() {
    ngDialog.openConfirm({
        template: 'chatBox.html',
        controller: 'msgController',
        closeByDocument: false,
        closeByEscape: false,
        scope: $scope //Pass the scope object if you need to access in the template
    }).then(
        function(value) {
            //You need to implement the saveForm() method which should return a promise object
            $scope.closeChat().then(

            );
        },
        function(value) {
            //Cancel or do nothing
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  closeByDocument: false, instead of backdrop to prevent the page from closing on background click.

```
    template: 'chatBox.html',
    controller: 'msgController',
    closeByDocument: false,
    keyboard: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `backdrop: 'static'` on your modal while open it while `$uibModal.open()`:

```
$uibModal.open({
    template: 'chatBox.html',
    controller: 'msgController',
    backdrop: 'static', // <--
    ...
});
```

Have a look to [AngularUI `modal` docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal).

Comment: What is $uibModal? Can u be more specific

Comment: @Kavipriya It is the modal from AngularUI. See the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) that is how you open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ngDialog doesn't support backdrop static. So it's better to use $model.open

```
$scope.openChatBox = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    template: 'chatBox.html',
                    controller: 'msgController',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    scope: $scope
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                    function(value) {
                       // do something
                   },
                   function(value) {
                      //Cancel or do nothing
                   }
                });
}
```

Comment: If I use `modal.open`, then how should I open the modal on button click?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I should include `ui-bootstrap` in dependency. and pass $modal to the controller. right? It is not working even after include. I edited the question and put full code.

Comment: Yes you have to inject $modal inside the controller

Comment: I get this error, "Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error", after injecting $modal

Comment: Did you include `angular-bootstrap` to your index.html?

Comment: Yeah I have included that. Now I have a doubt, whether that is the correct file because of the error.

Comment: What is the file you included?? `angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js` ??

Comment: Thanks that was very useful. But I found the options for `ngDialog` itself.

Comment: Great.. Happy Coding